# Exponential Stability and Lasalle's Invariance Theorem

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

It is well known that a system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is exponentially stable if there exists a Lyapunov function $V(x)$ which satisfies

\begin{align}
k_1\Vert x \Vert \leq V(x) &\leq k_2\Vert x \Vert \\
\dot{V} &\leq -k_3\Vert x \Vert.
\end{align}

Can we say something about exponential convergence to the set $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \dot{V}=0 \}$ if we replace the second equation by a positive semidefinite condition, i.e.

$$\dot{V} \leq -k_3\Vert x_1 \Vert, $$

where $x_1$ contains only some of the components of $x$, e.g. $x = (x_1^\top , x_2^\top)^\top$. From the invariance principle, we know in fact that the system converges to the set $S$, but not if it converges exponentially. I could not find anything in this regard in the standard nonlinear systems books by Khalil, Sepulchre, etc.

Can we say anything about the exponential convergence to $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let us rewrite the conditions of the theorem in an alternative, more convenient form (as in the Khalil's book):
$$\tag{1}
k_1\Vert x \Vert^a \leq V(x) \leq k_2\Vert x \Vert^a 
$$
$$\tag{2}
\dot{V} \leq -k_3\Vert x \Vert^a,
$$
$k_1,k_2,k_3,a>0$. Consider the system
$$\tag{3}
\dot x_1=-x_1,\quad \dot x_2=-f(x_2),
$$
where $f(x)$ is some function that satisfies the existence and uniqueness conditions, $\forall x\ne0\;\;xf(x)> 0$, $f(0)=0$. Let's choose
$V(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$. Then
$$
\dot V= -2x_1^2-2x_2f(x_2)\le -2x_1^2.
$$
Noticing that condition (1) is satisfied ($k_1=1$, $k_2=1$, $a=2$) and
$\dot V\le -2\Vert x_1\Vert^a$, we should obtain (if our guess is true) exponential stability for any $f(x_2)$ that satisfies the above conditions. This is obviously false. It is easy to come up with a differential equation of type $\dot x_2=-f(x_2)$, solutions of which do not tend to the equilibrium at an exponential rate.

(Update) Here the set $S$ contains only equilibrium because
$$\dot V=-2x_1^2-2x_2f(x_2)=0 \;\Leftrightarrow\; x_1=x_2=0;$$ therefore, there is no exponential tendency towards $S$. As for the exponential tendency of some of the variables to zero, this is called exponential stability with respect to part of the variables. It was described in some articles and books. For example, there is an article (it is, however, in Russian): https://www.mathnet.ru/eng/dan5135

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one question: Couldn't we say that since we use here $\dot{V} \leq -2x_1^2$, we converge to the invariant set $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_1 = 0 \}$, which would imply that $x_1$ may converge to zero (maybe) exponentially, but $x_2$ not? Or I am maybe computing the wrong $S$, because I used $\dot{V} = -2x_1^2$ when in fact I should have used the "real" $\dot{V}$ before the overestimation with $-2x_1^2$?

Comment: @Trb2 I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, also for the reference. Sadly, I cannot understand it. So, it would be wrong to use an overapproximation of $\dot{V}$ in order to compute the set S? I am still thinking on the example, because it is clear "by inspection" that x1 converges exponentially fast to zero... x2 not always, though. Can we maybe explain that somehow else?

Comment: @Trb2 1. Google translator can translate text from a picture. 2. I don't understand what exactly do you mean by "overapproximation of $\dot V$". 3. If the example I gave seems too simple and obvious to you, you can always do some tricky variable change with the system (3), after which things will get complicated.

Comment: By overapproximation I mean: Considering $\dot V= -2x_1^2-2x_2f(x_2)\leq -2x_1^2 := \dot{V}_{\rm over}$, can I define S with $\dot{V}_{\rm over}=0$, which would lead to the set where $x_1 = 0$, where exponential stability is given? Probably, I am looking for an answer to whether the system converges to the positively invariant set $E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_1=0 \}$ exponentially, i.e. exponential convergence to an attractor. What do you think?

Comment: @Trb2 If the inequality $\dot V_{over}\le -k V_{over}$, $k>0$ is satisfied for some  $V_{over}$, then you can apply the comparison lemma in the same way as in the proof of the exponential stability theorem (see, for example, Khalil's book). The original Lyapunov function $V$ is not needed for this.